# mysql Join Query for Result from two table

Tags: mysql, join

I have Two Table One to store Questions and Other to store Replies to Questions as Below

I have Shown the Table Structure and Column in table as Below

**Question Table**

```
Question_Id(PK)   |   Question   |   Name   |  EmailAddress
```

**Answer Table**

```
Answer_Id  |  Question_Id  |   Question  |   Name  |  EmailAddress
```

What ever question is posted it will be added to Question table and What ever Replies people post will be added to answer table

Now when ever Some one post a Reply to Question I Should Send mail to one who Posted Question and to those who posted Replies to the Question

Please Suggest a mysql Query for the above

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should know in the application the id of the question (qid) someone is replying to. Based on this id you can issue the following query:

```
Select EmailAddress from Question where Question_Id=qid
Union
Select EmailAddress from answer where Question_id=qid
```

Depending on the logic of your application this might also select the address of the current user. If you want to avoid this you should include in both select statments a condition to exclude the current replier. Something like:

```
Select EmailAddress from Question where Question_Id=qid and EmailAddress!=curentUserAddress
Union
Select EmailAddress from answer where Question_id=qid and EmailAddress!=curentUserAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from questions 
left join answers 
on questions.id = answers.question_id 
where question_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Question q, Answer a 
where q.Question_Id = a.Question_id and
      q.Question_Id = question_id
```